# MATLAB "bug" (or really weird behavior) with structs and empty cell arrays

Tags: matlab, cell-array, matlab-struct

I have no idea what's going on here. I'm using R2006b. Any chance someone out there with a newer version could test to see if they get the same behavior, before I file a bug report?

code: (`bug1.m`)

```
function bug1
S = struct('nothing',{},'something',{});
add_something(S, 'boing');          % does what I expect
add_something(S.something,'test');  % weird behavior
end

function add_something(X,str)
    disp('X=');
    disp(X);
    disp('str=');
    disp(str);
end
```

output:

```
>> bug1
X=
str=
boing
X=
test
str=
??? Input argument "str" is undefined.

Error in ==> bug1>add_something at 11
    disp(str);

Error in ==> bug1 at 4
add_something(S.something,'test');
```

It looks like the emptiness/nothingness of `S.something` allows it to shift the arguments for a function call. This seems like Very Bad Behavior. In the short term I want to find away around it (I'm trying to make a function that adds items to an initially empty cell array that's a member of a structure).

**Edit:**

Corollary question: so there's no way to construct a `struct` literal containing any empty cell arrays?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you already discovered yourself, this isn't a bug but a "feature". In other words, it is the normal behavior of the [STRUCT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/struct.html) function. If you pass empty cell arrays as field values to STRUCT, it assumes you want an empty structure array with the given field names.

```
>> s=struct('a',{},'b',{})

s = 

0x0 struct array with fields:
    a
    b
```

To pass an empty cell array as an actual field value, you would do the following:

```
>> s = struct('a',{{}},'b',{{}})

s = 

    a: {}
    b: {}
```

Incidentally, *any* time you want to set a field value to a cell array using STRUCT requires that you encompass it in another cell array. For example, this creates a single structure element with fields that contain a cell array and a vector:

```
>> s = struct('strings',{{'hello','yes'}},'lengths',[5 3])

s = 

    strings: {'hello'  'yes'}
    lengths: [5 3]
```

But this creates an array of two structure elements, distributing the cell array but *replicating* the vector:

```
>> s = struct('strings',{'hello','yes'},'lengths',[5 3])

s = 

1x2 struct array with fields:
    strings
    lengths

>> s(1)

ans = 

    strings: 'hello'
    lengths: [5 3]

>> s(2)

ans = 

    strings: 'yes'
    lengths: [5 3]
```

Comment: AH: thanks -- I didn't see the notes in the struct function that talk about using extra braces whenever you want to pass in a cell array. Grrr.

Answer (score 2):

ARGH... I think I found the answer. [`struct()`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/struct.html) has multiple behaviors, including:

> Note   If any of the values fields is
>   an empty cell array {}, the MATLAB
>   software creates an empty structure
>   array in which all fields are also
>   empty.

and apparently if you pass a member of a 0x0 structure as an argument, it's like some kind of empty phantom that doesn't really show up in the argument list. (that's still probably a bug)

bug2.m:

```
function bug2(arg1, arg2)
disp(sprintf('number of arguments = %d\narg1 = ', nargin));
disp(arg1);
```

test case:

```
>> nothing = struct('something',{})

nothing = 

0x0 struct array with fields:
    something

>> bug2(nothing,'there')
number of arguments = 2
arg1 = 
>> bug2(nothing.something,'there')
number of arguments = 1
arg1 = 
there
```

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour persists in 2008b, and is in fact not really a bug (although i wouldn't say the designers intended for it):
When you step into add_something(S,'boing') and watch the first argument (say by selecting it and pressing F9), you'd get *some* output relating to the empty structure S.
Step into add_something(S.something,'test') and watch the first argument, and you'd see it's in fact interpreted as 'test' !

The syntax struct.fieldname is designed to return an object of type 'comma separated list'. Functions in matlab are designed to receive an object of this exact type: the argument names are given to the values in the list, in the order they are passed.  In your case, since the first argument is an **empty list**, the comma-separated-list the function receives starts really at the second value you pass - namely, 'test'.

Comment: Actually, the designers *did* intend for this behavior. The syntax for passing arguments to the STRUCT function is designed such that you can create either a structure containing arrays or an array of structures, depending on your use of cell array encapsulation of the input arguments.

Comment: Also, the comma-separated list (CSL) behavior is intended as well. Input and output argument lists are designed as CSLs, and the following syntaxes create a CSL: structureArray.fieldName, cellArray{:}.

Comment: Of course both the behaviours you describe are by design. However, as just seen - a situation where several arguments are passed to a function and one in the middle is an empty CSL, entails consequences of this design that are *sure* to cause confusion. Such a scenario (seems to me) justifies separate design attention. At least, say, raise a runtime warning.

Answer (score 1):

Output is identical in R2008b:

```
>> bug1
X=
str=
boing
X=
test
str=
??? Input argument "str" is undefined.

Error in ==> bug1>add_something at 11
    disp(str);

Error in ==> bug1 at 4
add_something(S.something,'test');  % weird behavior
```